# Find all ContextMenuStrips in Windows Form

Tags: c#, contextmenu

How is it possible to loop through all ContextMenus within a Windows Form?

What I currently have is:

```
public void SearchContextMenuStrip(Form Window)
{
    foreach (Control item in Window.Controls)
    {
        if (item is ContextMenuStrip)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ContextMenuStrip found!", "ContextMenuStrip found");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This works fine for all other controls but not for the ContextMenus.

I want this to be able to translate all text for a multi language application so if someone knows a better solution for this it is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thinks this is a bad solution for the localization. Please read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx.

Comment: Window.Controls will give only top level Controls on your form. Each control also have a Controls collection, and you need to iterate over it (you need recursion).

Comment: ContextMenuStrip is not a control so you can never find it back through the Controls property.  You'll have to iterate `components` instead.  That doesn't always work but does for ContextMenuStrip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate **just one `ContextMenuStrip` to each control** so I think you want `ToolStripMenuItem`

```
foreach( var item in Window.ContextMenuStrip.Items)
{
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks! Small footnote: you miss the word 'in' in the brackets of the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Use resx file and for each region-language create it with translation. Use the settings.NAME instead of hard coding. Localization will be applied automatically.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992030(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I've played with it. Downside of this method (afaik) is that e.g. when you have 10 buttons with 'hello' in it and you want to have 5 languages, you have to change 50 occurrences of the word 'hello' in 5 separate files. By building my own translate sequence it is only required to change 5 words in only one file in a format which everybody can get (because translation will probably be done by 'less clever' non technicians). I don't get the advance of the standard way... But if you know a standard way which isn't that devious it would be awesome! I would be very interested in such a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is using reflection and finding the ContextMenuStrips between all objects. this script will be able to return all ContextMenuStrips.

```
    public static bool IsLastObject(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return true;
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        return 
            type.IsArray ||
            type.IsEnum ||
            type.IsPointer ||
            type.IsAbstract ||
            type.IsSealed;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(object obj, int maxNests = 25)
    {
        if (obj == null || maxNests < 0) yield break;
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
        if (obj is Control)
            foreach (Control item in ((Control)obj).Controls)
            {
                list.Add(item);
                yield return item;
            }
        foreach (var item in type.GetFields())
        {
            var nobj = item.GetValue(obj);
            if (nobj == null) continue;
            if (nobj is Control && !list.Contains((Control)nobj)) yield return (Control)nobj;
            if (IsLastObject(nobj)) continue;
            foreach (var ni in GetAllControls(nobj, maxNests - 1))
                yield return ni;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ContextMenuStrip> GetAllToolStrips(object control, int maxNests = 25)
    {
        foreach (var item in GetAllControls(control, maxNests))
            if (item is ContextMenuStrip) yield return (ContextMenuStrip)item;
    }
```

Enjoy...